# How to carry my pick list value in wizard..?

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, save-and-new

I am trying to build one custom Wizard in which I have three pick list fields. In page no 4 I am having one save button if I click that it should save my selected picklist value.

My Apex Code is:

```
public class Mywizard{

 FeedbackFrom__c Fed;

   public FeedbackFrom__c getFed() {
      if(Fed== null) Fed = new FeedbackFrom__c();
      return Fed;
   }
   public PageReference step1() {
      return Page.Questionarypage1;
   }

   public PageReference step2() {
      return Page.Questionarypage2;
   }

   public PageReference step3() {
      return Page.Questionarypage3;
   }
   public PageReference cancel() {
            PageReference FeedbackPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Fed).view();
            FeedbackPage.setRedirect(true);
            return FeedbackPage; 
    }
    public PageReference save() {


      ///How to carry my picklist value here





       PageReference FeedbackPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Fed).view();
       FeedbackPage.setRedirect(true);

       return FeedbackPage;
   }

}
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: The `StandardController` constructor expects a variable of type `SObject`. You need to pass your `Fed` variable instead of a type: `new ApexPages.StandardController(Fed)`

Comment: What is the issue? If all the three picklists are part of `FeedbackFrom__c` it will be automatically available in the `Fed` variable and you can save it.

Comment: +1 to Seroj's comment, with the proviso that all the pages must reference the same controller i.e. your `Mywizard`.